# Is there anyway to view historical performance of SQL 2008 R2 database?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

So.. I was wondering, is there a way for me to generate any report for the historical performance of a MS SQL database? I'm originally an Oracle DBA, but now I'm requested to support a few SQL databases in my office as there's nobody supporting it now.
Being an Oracle DBA, I know where to look if I need any reports related to DB performance e.g. AWR & Statspack but now MS SQL DB. 
Going around google doesn't yield any result as well unfortunately, since most requested me to turn on SQL profiler to run the trace, which I can't since it will cause even more load to the high loaded server. 
Is there a way to configure the DB to take snapshots every half hour and combine it into a report like how AWR / Statspack behave in Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

### System Dynamic Management Views

You might want to dive into the **[Execution Related Dynamic Management Views and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/execution-related-dynamic-management-views-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)** that reside in a SQL Server instance. These views and functions do contains some information related to performance.

The suggested views and functions are a sub-set of the **[System Dynamic Management Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/system-dynamic-management-views?view=sql-server-ver15)** which contain various other sub-sets of views and functions, which may or may not be what you are looking for.

#### Further sub-sets

- [Database Related Dynamic Management Views (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/database-related-dynamic-management-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Index Related Dynamic Management Views and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/index-related-dynamic-management-views-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [I O Related Dynamic Management Views and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/i-o-related-dynamic-management-views-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Memory-Optimized Table Dynamic Management Views (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/memory-optimized-table-dynamic-management-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Transaction Related Dynamic Management Views and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/transaction-related-dynamic-management-views-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- ...

<sup>*(Just to name a few)*</sup>

> **Note**
>   Most of these views  are recycled after an instance restart. You will have to dump the information to static tables in a (e.g.) Admin database if you want to retain historical data.

### Built-In Reports

If you right-click on a database and move your mouse pointer into the reports, then you might find can occasional jewel of information:

[image: Picture showing the context menu on a database, when selecting the item Reports, then the sub-menu Standard Reports and then the sub-menu displaying the various options.]

### Creating a Baseline for SQL Server

There is an extensive Q&A on DBA.SE with the title [Creating SQL Server Performance Baseline Monitoring](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/111258/15356) which show you how you could baseline a SQL Server instance. The article references other material.

And then you could start reading Erin Stellato's article [5 Reasons You Must Start Capturing Baseline Data](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/5-reasons-you-must-start-capturing-baseline-data) for an interesting start into SQL Server "baselining".

### Answering Your Question

> So.. I was wondering, is there a way for me to generate any report for the historical performance of a MS SQL database?

There are indeed a couple of ways with the **Management Views and Functions** and **Standard Reports**. For a deep dive you are going to either build something yourself or purchase a third-party tool.

Answer (score 1):

I use Brent Ozar's [First Responder Kit PowerBI Dashboard](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/first-responder-kit-power-bi-dashboard/). You install some procs, create a table to store the data and then schedule a job to populate the data.

You can drill down into performance of specific queries and lots of other cool stuff.

Answer (score 1):

As for built-in features, older versions of SQL Server have the [Management Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-collection/management-data-warehouse?view=sql-server-ver15), which will collect performance data and store it in a separate database, optionally on a separate server.

Newer versions add the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) which will automatically record query plans and stats, as well as query wait stats.  And newer versions track [wait stats at the session level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, no. SQL Server does have a default trace, but the range of events captured is quite small https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/a-few-cool-things-you-can-identify-using-the-default-trace.html and not much history is kept.

Extended Events are the server-side replacement for SQL Profiler, but there is a bit of a learning curve and you kind of already need to know what you are interested in.

A third party monitoring tool might be an option - maybe a free trial or demo version? If not, you could roll your own using PerfMon. SQL Server exposes a lot of counters which will give you stats on executions, locks, CPU, IO and so on, see https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/using-perfmon-and-pal-to-diagnose-sql-issues . It won't give you information about individual SQL statements though. Newer versions of SQL Server have a feature called the Query Store, which has similarities to Oracle's Active Session History.

HTH